# Работа RegExp со строкой

Tags: регулярные-выражения, строки, ruby

Что-то с первого раза не въехал в regExp. Суть: есть строка URL, к примеру: `//mysite.com/uploads/library/111/name.jpg`
Ее нужно немного изменить, скажем на `//assets.mynewsite.com/uploads` - дальше то же самое.

Нашел выход:

```
 a = url.split('uploads')
 a.delete_at(0)
 b = a.map { |i| i.to_s }.join(""))
 url = '//assets.mynewsite.com/upload' + b
```

Но понимаю, что это какие-то дикие костыли.

Может, кто знает как сделать элегантно с помощью regexp?

Comment: Вам просто нужно заменить `mysite.com` на `assets.mynewsite.com`? Я правильно вас понял?

Comment: по сути да, но вместо mysite.com может быть другой домен...

Comment: И как я заметил вы в `url` написали `upload`, А в коде уже `url.split('uploads')`. Может у вас это вызывает ошибку?

Comment: просто описка:) извиняюсь

Comment: Помогла регулярка?

Comment: уже есть кое-что:) желаемого пока не добился)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я ноль по `ruby`))), но по регулярке могу помочь.
Вот эта регулярка выберит все что между `//` и следующему `/`.

```
#\/\/(.[^\/]*)\/#
```

А вот [ссылка](https://regex101.com/r/wU4gg8/1/) для проверки работы регулярного выражения.

Ну а что бы проверить работу регулярки именно для `ruby`, можете использовать вот этот [сайт](http://rubular.com/).

Comment: точно, выбирает:) спасибо.. а ее можно подменить на другое выражение?)

Comment: @rostov-7 Можно сделать что хотите, но для этого дополните вопрос, или задайте новый? Ну а если ответ вам подошел полностью то отметте галочкой как принятый ответ.